# Why was the day of the week consistently off by one day?

Tags: mr-robot

From S02E01:

[image]

But the actual 2015-06-11 was a Thursday. (Note though that the actual 2014-06-11 was indeed a Wednesday.)

---

From S02E08:

[image]

The top of the screen says "Sun July 6". But the actual 2015-07-06 was a Monday. (Note though that the actual 2014-07-06 was indeed a Sunday.)

---

From S0304:

> Irving: Well, this is just a little Monday morning staff meeting update kinda thing.

> Angela: Today's Friday.

...

> Irving: We go on September 29th, ten days from now.

But the actual 2015-09-19 was a Saturday. (While the actual 2014-09-19 was indeed a Friday.)

---

S04E01:

[image]

Screen says "Sun Dec 21" and "2015-DEC-21".

But the actual 2015-12-21 was a Monday. (While the actual 2014-09-19 was indeed a Sunday.)

---

More: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MrRobot/comments/509d9p/spoilers_s02e08_angelas_off_by_one_bug/).

---

Much more than most other TV shows/movies, Mr Robot was not shy about letting the viewer know the specific dates of many events. So it's puzzling that they could have made such a "mistake" (if it be a mistake).

---

Some possibilities I can think of:

- While filming S01 in 2014, they mistakenly used 2014 days of the week, then decided to stick with this mistake throughout the rest of the series anyway.
- Signal that maybe the Mr Robot world isn't the same as our real world. (And perhaps some connection to Whiterose's project.)

I wonder if the writers/producers may have said anything about this?

Comment: My question would be whether it's a *consistent* mistake (in which case it's likely a deliberate decision on the part of the makers) or whether these images have cherry-picked from various episodes to prove a point. Are there examples when the day was correct (or off by more than one day)?

Comment: I've twitted at the show's makers. Hopefully they'll respond.

Comment: The show is about programmers, so maybe its calendar starts at 0 A.D. instead of 1 A.D.